# What is the maximum number of characters that nvarchar(MAX) will hold?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to the concept `nvarchar(MAX)`. How many characters will it hold?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Max. capacity is 2 gigabytes of space - so you're looking at just over 1 billion 2-byte characters that will fit into a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` field.

Using the other answer's more detailed numbers, you should be able to store

```
(2 ^ 31 - 1 - 2) / 2 = 1'073'741'822 double-byte characters

1 billion, 73 million, 741 thousand and 822 characters to be precise
```

in your `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column (unfortunately, that last half character is wasted...)

**Update:** as @MartinMulder pointed out: any variable length character column also has a 2 byte overhead for storing the actual length - so I needed to subtract two more bytes from the `2 ^ 31 - 1` length I had previously stipulated - thus you can store 1 Unicode character less than I had claimed before.

Comment: Wow... so i guess i don't really need to worry about setting a max size validation rule then. I had better be carefull about when I use the nvarchar(MAX) though.

Comment: @quakkels: unless you plan to top Tolstoi' War and Peace (approx. 3.1 million characters) almost 350 times over - no, you won't have to worry about capacity :-) And since it's a VARCHAR/NVARCHAR type, it will always only use as much space as needed - no worries about wasted or unnecessarily reserved space either...

Comment: really? That's cool. Just out of curiosit, in what case would you not want to use nvarchar(MAX)?

Comment: @quakkels: use `VARCHAR(MAX)`, if you don't need the 2-byte support for Asian, Arab or Cyrillic languages. Use `(N)VARCHAR(x)` if you know a string will never be longer than x characters (don't use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for a first name - use `NVARCHAR(50)` or whatever makes sense to you)

Comment: Tes, @quakkels, I only use specific sizes on `[n]varchar` to help enforce business rules. I know the DB isn't the place for business logic, but it is a very convenient and practical place to enforce certain rules, especially when dealing with multiple data sources outside just one app.

Comment: I just started my morning asking me the same question and both of your answers conjured a big smile on my face. +1.

Comment: Should it not be `(2 ^ 31 - 3) / 2`? Since there are always 2 bytes extra needed for "administration"? See also the answer of Adriaan Stander.

Comment: @MartinMulder: possibly - but compared to 1 billion, 73 million characters, you're really splitting hairs here.....

Comment: @marc_s: True... it is not really import to me. But the OP ask for "how many", and "a lot" will not cover it. So in your answer you state "to be precise", and you did a very "precise" calculation (with `-1`). And I point out it may be `-3`... to be even more precise. Bottom line: Or your answer is precise or it is an approximation. Lets be transparant about it.

Answer (score 12):

From [char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ]
>
> Variable-length, non-Unicode character
> data. n can be a value from 1 through
> 8,000. **max indicates that the
> maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes.
> The storage size is the actual length
> of data entered + 2 bytes.** The data
> entered can be 0 characters in length.
> The ISO synonyms for varchar are char
> varying or character varying.

Answer (score 5):

2^31-1 bytes. So, a little less than 2^31-1 characters for varchar(max) and half that for nvarchar(max).

[nchar and nvarchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)