# How many chars are available in nvarchar(MAX)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @string nvarchar(MAX) = ''
```

How many chars are available in @string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum characters for the NVARCHAR(MAX)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131958/what-is-the-maximum-characters-for-the-nvarcharmax)

Comment: @mod: better/older duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270049/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-characters-that-nvarcharmax-will-hold

Answer (score 8, accepted):

nvarchar(MAX) will hold up to 2GB which is about 1 billion characters since it is unicode

in your case it is 0

also take a look at this, datalength counts storage, len counts characters, for varchar these will be the same

```
declare @string nvarchar(MAX) = ''
select datalength(@string), LEN(@string)
GO

declare @string nvarchar(MAX) = '1'
select datalength(@string), LEN(@string)
```

Comment: What happens it I declare `varchar(MAX)` instead `nvarchar(MAX)`?

Comment: in that case you can go up to 2 billion characters

Comment: @darkcminor: 1 billion characters for NVARCHAR(MAX) is about 200 times the volume of Tolstoj's `War and Peace` - should be enough for **most** cases....

Answer (score 3):

You have about two billion bytes worth of Unicode characters to play with. From [the MSDN documentation for char and varchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

> Variable-length, non-Unicode character data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size is the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The data entered can be 0 characters in length. The ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.