# What is the maximum characters for the NVARCHAR(MAX)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have declared a column of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in SQL Server 2008, what would be its exact maximum characters having the MAX as the length?

Answer (score 599, accepted):

The max size for a column of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is 2 GByte of storage.

Since `NVARCHAR` uses 2 bytes per character, that's approx. 1 billion characters.

Leo Tolstoj's *War and Peace* is a 1'440 page book, containing about 600'000 words - so that might be 6 million characters - well rounded up. So you could stick about 166 copies of the entire *War and Peace* book into each `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column.

Is that enough space for your needs? :-)

Comment: Just a nit pick. NVARCHAR uses 2 bytes for most characters. For unicode caracters over U+00FFFF. It'll use four bytes.

Comment: Nitpicking: "The storage size is two times n bytes + 2 bytes." ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments))

Comment: "A common misconception is to think that NCHAR(n) and NVARCHAR(n), the n defines the number of characters. But in NCHAR(n) and NVARCHAR(n) the n defines the string length in **byte-pairs**" ([Source])(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

Answer (score 88):

> By default, nvarchar(MAX) values are stored exactly the same as nvarchar(4000) values would be, unless the actual length exceed 4000 characters; in that case, the in-row data is replaced by a pointer to one or more seperate pages where the data is stored.

If you anticipate data possibly exceeding 4000 character, nvarchar(MAX) is definitely the recommended choice.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/databasedesign/thread/d5e0c6e5-8e44-4ad5-9591-20dc0ac7a870/

Comment: It is also NOT recomended if your data will never exceed 4000 characters as there are indexing issues.

Comment: I believe this to be outdated. See answer from @marc_s.

Comment: Hi @FabioMilheiro , can I ask which part is outdated. Is that the pointer storage part?

Answer (score 15):

From [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)

> **nvarchar** [ ( n | **max** ) ]
>
> Variable-length Unicode string data. *n* defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. **max** indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB).
> The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes

Answer (score 13):

I think actually `nvarchar(MAX)` can store approximately 1070000000 chars.

Comment: Can you explain where you're getting that number, and what you mean by "accurately"? (i.e. are you saying that's not a hard limit, but with more characters there can be problems? What kinds of problems? Why?)

Comment: I am not sure, but I think, if nvarchar uses double space than varchar to store a char , and the maximun number of memory that can be used by nvarchar(MAX) to store chars is  2^31-1 => 2147483647, then 2147483647/2 is 1073741824. by accurately I mean that is not an exact number.