# Does nvarchar(max) only allow 4000 characters?

Tags: sql-server-2012, nvarchar

In the query below nvarchar(max) seems to truncate at 4000 characters.
That seems contrary to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131958/what-is-the-maximum-characters-for-the-nvarcharmax) which says "Since NVARCHAR uses 2 bytes per character, that's approx. 1 billion characters."

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i=0
set @test=cast('x' as nvarchar(max))

while(@i<6000)
begin
set @test= (@test+ cast('x' as nvarchar(max)))
set @i=@i+1

end

print @TEST--has only 4000 characters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, just found out that this is a limitation of the message screen in Sql server management studio. The code below shows correct results

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i=0
set @test=cast('x' as nvarchar(max))

while(@i<6000)
begin
set @test= (@test+ cast('x' as nvarchar(max)))
set @i=@i+1

end

print len(@TEST)--6001
```

Comment: Wow, yes, that's *bizarre*! Using `print` with an nvarchar(max) will only print the first 4000 characters! Great find. Hey Microsoft: How about you fix your shit? :)