# SQL Server Populate XML Variable from VARCHAR rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I have a single column table in SQL Server.

This column hold each row of an XML document.

Sample table :

```
         Column
---------------
Row1:    <ROOT>
Row2:    <Name>name1</Name>
Row3:    </ROOT>
```

Column data type is `nvarchar(max)`

I want to do:

```
DECLARE @RES_XML XML

SET @XML = Set from table above
```

How can I sum up all rows of the table above and populate `@RES_XML`?

**Note:** when concatenated; all data in the table exceeds `nvarchar(max)` limit.

Comment: `<Name="name1">` is not valid XML.

Comment: You will at least need a second column to order the table by. If you don't specify the ordering, select statements will return rows ordered at random.

Comment: You're **exceeding** the 2 GB (2 ***billion*** character) limit? REALLY?!?!? That's about **200 times** the whole text of Leo Tolstoj's *War and Peace* - a very thick book to begin with ....

Comment: @marc_s according to [your own answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11131977/2684660) it is actually **1** billion characters (**n**varchar has 2 bytes per character) which amounts to about 166 copies. I do like the unit of measure here though, 166 W&P of storage. And I wonder how many kW&P OP would need for their xml document.

Comment: @funkwurm: gosh - you're right :-) Sorry - good enough for at least 100 copies of "War & Peace" - but even that is hard to exceed ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In general, easiest way to concatenate values into variable is

```
declare @res nvarchar(max)

select @res = isnull(@res, '') + [Column]
from <table above>

select cast(@res as xml)
```

Of course, order of concatenation in this query is not defined (but there is a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13744550/1744834) to check if order is maintained)

Answer (score 0):

I am as surprised by your exceeding the limit of `nvarchar(max)` columns as Marc is, but maybe you have column limit settings in your database set-up that you can't change. Here's how I would do it, and I'm assuming there is *some* column that let's you order the tags in the appropriate order, you cannot rely on the order in which the database decided to store and retrieve the rows.

```
declare @t table (
    id int,
    x nvarchar(max)
)

insert into @t
select 1, '<ROOT>' union all
select 2, '<Name>name1</Name>' union all
select 3, '</ROOT>'

DECLARE @RES_XML XML

select @RES_XML = cast((
        select x
        from @t
        order by id
        for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as xml)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still bump up against the nvarchar(max) ceiling when cast in the .value()  ?  OP says "when concatenated; all data in the table exceeds nvarchar(max) limit"

Comment: @NathanSkerl My assumption is that OP's column-restrictions are more limited than that of an `nvarchar(max)` variable. If it really is the 2 GB limit then I don't know how to help them, Roman Pekar's answer would run into the same problem because his `@res` is also `nvarchar(max)`