# What is the replacement for datatype(max) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was transferring data from a SQL Server database to another database (PDW).In source table there is a column with datatype (max). In destination it doesn't support datatype (max).

So what is the max value SQL Server considers for a dataype (max)?

Comment: What **exact** datatype are you talking about? `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARBINARY(MAX)` ?? And why shouldn't those types be supported in your target system - isn't that SQL Server also?

Comment: i was looking for nvarchar(max).

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131958/what-is-the-maximum-characters-for-the-nvarcharmax)

Comment: `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is a Unicode string column, with a maximum of 1 billion characters. So whatever your other RDBMS offers that supports this - pick that. `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in SQL Server is available from SQL Server **2005** on - it wasn't available in 2000 and earlier versions.

Comment: What is your target DB type is?

Comment: if PDW = parallel data warehouse then VARCHAR(MAX) is supported, as stated by the [documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/6/42616D71-3488-46E2-89F0-E516C10F6576/SQL_Server_to_SQL_Server_PDW_Migration_Guide.pdf) (see page 29, type mapping).

Comment: ok..Thank you guys for your help.
Yes its Parallel data warehouse i was trying in convert function in select query.

SELECT top 10 
convert (nvarchar(max),<column name>) as < Destination column name>

 FROM <Table name>

Answer (score 0):

If you run the first line of code but put the particular column name and table name in (instead of [columname] and [tablename]).

Then run the second line of code with the table name and column name again replacing [columname] and [tablename], but with the number produced by the first piece of code between the brackets after nvarchar.

This will alter the column from max to a defined nvarchar length and maybe the other database should recognise this.

```
select max(len([columnname])) from [tablename]

alter table [tablename] alter column [columname] nvarchar()
```