# What is the Maximum character limit for nvarchar(Max) in LocalDB?

Tags: c#, database, localdb

While saving my record form C# to LocalDB, my strings get truncated although I am using NVarChar(Max) as column type.

Any Suggestions to fix this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131958/what-is-the-maximum-characters-for-the-nvarcharmax

Comment: Fix what? You haven't posted the code that shows the problem. If the data was too long you'd get an exception, not truncation

Comment: "max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB)" - are you sure your strings are being truncated on the DB, not by parameter coercion etc?

Comment: already answered.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131958/what-is-the-maximum-characters-for-the-nvarcharmax

Comment: Also, people frequently mistake what the *client tools* do with long values (often truncating them for display purposes with no indication that this has occurred) rather than understanding that the entire value *is* present in the underlying table and *is* retrievable, just not when using the ad-hoc querying tools.

Comment: @Stanley the answer says *NOT* 4000. It's 2GB