# MS SQL does not allow VARCHAR over 128 characters, why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column configured to hold `nvarchar` data type.
I am trying to add a row using

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES (value1, value2...)
```

Sql-server gets stuck on a 180 character string that I am trying to assign to the `nvarchar` data type column returning:

> Error: The identifier that starts with [part of string] is too long.
>   Maximum length is 128.

I don't understand why this is happening since nvarchar(max) should hold 2GByte of storage as I read here: [What is the maximum characters for the NVARCHAR(MAX)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131958/what-is-the-maximum-characters-for-the-nvarcharmax)

Any ideas of what I've got wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

The table was created with this:

```
CREATE TABLE MED_DATA (
    MED_DATA_ID INT
    ,ORDER_ID INT
    ,GUID NVARCHAR
    ,INPUT_TXT NVARCHAR
    ,STATUS_CDE CHAR
    ,CRTE_DTM DATETIME
    ,MOD_AT_DTM DATETIME
    ,CHG_IN_REC_IND CHAR
    ,PRIMARY KEY (MED_DATA_ID)
    )
```

And my actual INSERT statement is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO MED_DATA
VALUES (
    5
    ,12
    ,"8fd9924"
    ,"{'firstName':'Foo','lastName':'Bar','guid':'8fd9924','weightChanged':false,'gender':'Male','heightFeet':9,'heightInches':9,'weightPounds':999}"
    ,"PENDING"
    ,"2017-09-02 00:00:00.000"
    ,"2017-09-02 00:00:00.000"
    ,NULL
    )
```

Comment: Show us the **real** sql you are using. "Identifier too long" suggests that you are trying a column **name** (not a value) that is too long

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, double quotes in T-SQL do *not* delimit a string. [They delimit an identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). So you cannot use double quotes here. You could change the default *but shouldn't*.

If this is being directly written in a query window, use single quotes for strings and then double up quotes within the string to escape them:

```
INSERT INTO MED_DATA VALUES (5, 12, '8fd9924', '{''firstName'':''Foo'',''lastName'':''Bar'',''guid'':''8fd9924'',''weightChanged'':false,''gender'':''Male'',''heightFeet'':9,''heightInches'':9,''weightPounds'':999}', 'PENDING', '2017-09-02T00:00:00.000', '2017-09-02T00:00:00.000', NULL)
```

But if, instead, you're passing this string across from another program, it's time to learn how to use parameterized queries. That'll also allow you to pass the dates across *as* dates and not rely on string parsing to reconstruct them correctly.

Also, as noted, you need to [fix your table definitions](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) because they've currently `nvarchar` which means the same as `nvarchar(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of what an Identifier is? Here is a hint - it is a NAME. SQL Server is not complaining about your data, it is complaining about a field or table name. SOmehow your SQL must be totally borked so that part of the text is parsed as name of a field or table. And yes, those are limited to 128 characters.

This is clear in the error message:

> Error: The identifier

clearly states it is an identifier issue.

Comment: Borked? Running with the [default settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?