# Pymssql - insert large string - DBPROCESS is dead or not enabled

Tags: python, sql-server, limit, pymssql

I'm trying to insert a single row to a table that has a `nvarchar(max)` column (say response) using python's `pymssql` library.

The other columns are straightforward - one nvarchar(10) column, two nvarchar(30) columns, two date columns and one bigint column

I don't really have control over the length of the response string I get and as a result they can be of arbitrary length. Everywhere I've searched shows (e.g. [What is the maximum characters for the NVARCHAR(MAX)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131958/what-is-the-maximum-characters-for-the-nvarcharmax)) that `nvarchar(max)` can support up to a billion characters. However, the code I'm using seems to break at around the 130 million character mark.

Code:

```py
import pymssql
from pathlib import Path
conn = pymssql.connect('server', 'user', 'password', 'db')
content = Path('file.txt').read_text()
print(len(content)) # 547031539
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("Insert into table_name values (%s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s, %s)", ('2020-05-21', '2023-03-27T20:51:50.221718', '2023-03-27T19:34:02.103253', 127671, content[:133_949_006], 'New', '2020-05-22'))
conn.commit()
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MSSQLDatabaseException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
File src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx:461, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute()

File src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx:1087, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query()

File src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx:1118, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query()

File src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx:1251, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query()

File src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx:1789, in pymssql._mssql.check_cancel_and_raise()

File src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx:1835, in pymssql._mssql.raise_MSSQLDatabaseException()

MSSQLDatabaseException: (20047, b'DB-Lib error message 20047, severity 9:\nDBPROCESS is dead or not enabled\n')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[126], line 2
      1 with conn.cursor() as cursor:
----> 2     cursor.execute(Insert into table_name values (%s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s, %s)", ('2020-05-21', '2023-03-27T20:51:50.221718', '2023-03-27T19:34:02.103253', 127671, content[:133_949_006], 'New', '2020-05-22'))
      3 conn.commit()

File src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx:479, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute()

OperationalError: (20047, b'DB-Lib error message 20047, severity 9:\nDBPROCESS is dead or not enabled\n')
```

Comment: you want to put a 500 mb text into a Text column, wouldn't it be easier to save only the file path, it will take also ages to get the data back and sql server are not really the best place to save such big amount in one column

Comment: Agreed that this would be better. However, I do want to understand where the issue is here - is it at the FreeTDS layer (which is what pymssql uses) or an issue with pymssql or a limitation of SQL server itself or maybe with the database (perhaps some configurations)

Comment: Also - it errors out with only ~ 130 million characters. I ran a binary search to see where it starts erroring out for that file and it was at `133_949_006` characters

Comment: it will be one of the timeouts, as i said that isn't really a good thing for sql server but see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: The value is set at 600 for the db server. However the error message on the client side gets thrown in under a minute

Comment: almost all service make an entry  in the event log so that would be the first where to look, also has sqlserver his own log, which have to be enabled

Comment: @wkgrcdsam hello. I have same problem. Did you solved this prob?? In my case, when the failed task is retried continuously, at some point, it suddenly works well!!

Comment: Hi @SecY - unfortunately no. I saw some logs in the windows event viewer something about packet limits, but further googling on those didn't help much. I eventually resorted to storing that data in s3 and referencing the s3 urls in the table