# Keep upload file as json in database

Tags: c#, sql, json, sql-server, background-task

I upload a text file into my system. It consists of the file content as byte array. Then this content is parsed and converted in a C# class object with many relations.

I need to move this upload process in a background task. So, after upload, the UI thread lets the user do anything else, while in the background the files table is populated.

The background task is in a separate Console Library project `public class UploadFilesService : BackgroundService`. So it has no access to the uploaded files. I think I need to store them in a database table then the background task will fetch them and just call the upload process.

But the input files are big objects for a database table. I consider having a column 'ObjectAsJson' where the object plus the content byte array are converted to json. `nvarchar` has a limit for characters. The byte array surpasses that limit. The many-to-many relations add a lot of characters to this json and it surpasses this limit.

Before the background task there was no problem, because everything was temporary in memory. Now i consider the following solution:

Use [SQL Blob data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/binary-large-object-blob-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) for file's content.
Parse and convert again the input file in the C# class. This adds duplicity, because during upload I already parse and convert the file to validate the fields. And if the file is valid then theoretically its added in a queue to be fetched by the background task.

There is also an alternative [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) SQL datatype, but I think Blob is better.

How would you approach this problem? Of providing the input files to your background task.

Comment: `nvarchar(max)` has a limit of 2GB. Are your files larger than that?

Comment: I searched on google `nvarchar limit` and the first result said the limit is 3000 characters. [Website](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-varchar-data-type-deep-dive/#:~:text=Due%20to%20this%20reason%2C%20nvarchar,about%20nvarchar%20in%20SQL%20Server.) Now that you say, the website might be obsolete. I require around 100k-500k characters in a file.

Comment: I looked at that link and didn't find the number 3000 written in it anywhere. Additionally, that article relates to `varchar`, not `nvarchar`. The fact is, the largest `varchar` value you can specify that isn't `max` is `varchar(8000)`. The largest `nvarchar` value you can specify is half that, owing to `nvarchar` using 2 bytes per character. But all that is irrelevant, because if you specify `nvarchar(max)` you hold up to 2GB. 500k `nvarchar` characters would be about 1gb, so would hold your data.

Comment: edit: I'm sorry, I was off by an order of magnitude. 500k characters would be about 1 megabyte. nvarchar max can hold about 1 billion characters. [What is the maximum characters for the NVARCHAR(max)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131958/what-is-the-maximum-characters-for-the-nvarcharmax)

Comment: By mistake I said 3k. The site says 4000 characters. If it holds 1 billion, then it is enough for an object json. I don't know if its the best practice, but its good for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF maps a property string to nvarchar(max). According to [others answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11131958/9442199), it can keep 1 billion characters. This is enough to keep any object as json, even if it has many relations.